# calculate flux through surface

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I need to calculate the flux of the vector field $\vec{F}$ through the surface $D$, where
$$\vec{F} = \left<z, \, y \sqrt{x^2 + z^2}, \, -x \right> \\
D = \{x^2+6x+z^2\le 0 \,| -1\le y \le 0\}.$$

So there should be a cylinder (height on $y$ axis) shifted by 3 units (center $x=-3$), with cut on $ -1\le y \le 0$.

Cylindrical parametrization:

$$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos\theta -3\\
y=y\\
z=r\sin\theta
\end{cases}
$$

I think I can do this problem in two ways: The first one by calculating the flux for each of the 3 surfaces (1 cylinder, 2 disks), and the second one by using the divergence theorem.

$$\operatorname{div}F = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \overset{\text{cylindrical}}{\underset{\text{coordinates}}{=}} \sqrt{r^2-9-6r\cos\theta},$$

so with the divergence theorem, $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{3\sqrt{3}}\int_{-1}^{0}{r\sqrt{r^2-9-6r\cos\theta} \, dy \, dr \, d\theta}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Why did you write down $\;\int_0^{-1}\;$ instead of the obvious (and correct) $\;\int_{-1}^0\;$ ...? Then you get $\;18\pi\;$ . But for this, the rest seems to be correct...

Comment: ohh yep :P , my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where the $3\sqrt{3}$ comes from in your result, but there is indeed more than one way to evaluate this problem.

(1) Direct method

Here is some [technical information](http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes02/v9.pdf) about this method from MIT's open notes, and some [visualization](https://mathinsight.org/surface_integral_vector_field_introduction) for what the flux of a vector field through a surface is. Let the flux of a vector field $\vec{\mathbf{V}}$ through a surface $\Sigma$ be denoted $\Phi$ and defined
$$
\Phi := \iint_\Sigma \mathbf{\vec{V}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \, d\sigma.
$$
The vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the unit outward normal to the surface $\Sigma$. Suppose $\Sigma$ is given by $z = f(x,y).$ Let $\mathbf{\vec{r}}(x,y)$ trace $\Sigma$ such that
$$
\mathbf{\vec{r}}(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ f(x,y)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the unit normal $\mathbf{\vec{n}}$ is given by
$$
\mathbf{\vec{n}} = \frac{\mathbf{\vec{r}}_x \times \mathbf{\vec{r}}_y}{|| \mathbf{\vec{r}}_x \times \mathbf{\vec{r}}_y ||} =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{f_x^{\,2} + f_y^{\,2} + 1}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-f_x \\
-f_y \\
1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So given that $\mathbf{\vec{V}} = u(x,y,z) \mathbf{\hat{i}} + v(x,y,z) \mathbf{\hat{j}} + w(x,y,z) \mathbf{\hat{k}}$, the corresponding flux of $\mathbf{\vec{V}}$ through $\Sigma$ is
$$
\Phi = \iint_\Sigma \frac{-uf_x - vf_y + w}{\sqrt{f_x^{\,2} + f_y^{\,2} + 1}} \, d\sigma.
$$

For the given field, we have
$$\mathbf{\vec{V}} = z \mathbf{\hat{i}} + y \sqrt{x^2 + z^2} \mathbf{\hat{j}} - x \mathbf{\hat{k}},
$$
and the surface $\Sigma$ is given such that $(x + 3)^2 + z^2 = 9\ \forall y \in (-1,0).$
Thus we choose to trace the surface of the cylinder with
$$
\mathbf{\vec{r}}(x,z) =
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
(x + 3)^2 + z^2 - 9 \\
z
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where the unit outward normal on the cylinder is
$$\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4(x+3)^2 + 4z^2 + 1}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2(x+3) \\
1 \\
-2z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{37}}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2(x+3) \\
1 \\
-2z
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
The flux is then
\begin{align}
\Phi &= \underbrace{\iint_{\Sigma_1} \mathbf{\vec{V}} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ -1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \, d\sigma}_{y = -1} + \overbrace{\iint_{\Sigma_2} \mathbf{\vec{V}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \, d\sigma}^{\mathbf{\vec{V}}_2\text{ cannot contribute}} + \underbrace{\iint_{\Sigma_3} \mathbf{\vec{V}} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \, d\sigma}_{\text{nothing since }y = 0} \\
&= \iint_{\Sigma_1} \sqrt{x^2 + z^2} \, d\sigma + \frac{1}{\sqrt{37}}\iint_{\Sigma_2} -2z(x+3) + y\sqrt{x^2 + z^2} + 2xz \, d\sigma \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 r\sqrt{(r \cos\theta - 3)^2 + (r \sin\theta)^2} \, dr \, d\theta - \frac{6}{\sqrt{37}} \int_0^3 r^2  \, dr \, \underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} \sin\theta \, d\theta}_{0}  \\
&= 96.
\end{align}

---

(2) Divergence Theorem

[Technical information](http://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/suppnotes/suppnotes02/v10.pdf) about this method can also be found in MIT's open notes, and no visualization from the site this time, but the divergence theorem here is explained in [casual language](https://mathinsight.org/divergence_theorem_idea). Given everything is nice, the flux of the field through the surface is
$$
\iint_\Sigma \mathbf{\vec{V}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \, d\sigma = \iiint_M \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\vec{V}} \, dV,
$$
where $M$ is the bounded region contained within $\Sigma$.

Applying it to this problem, the divergence theorem takes us straight to the end result of the direct approach.
\begin{align}
\Phi &= \iint_\Sigma \nabla \cdot \mathbf{\vec{V}} \, dV \\
&= \iiint_M \sqrt{x^2 + z^2} \, dV \\
&= \int_{-1}^0 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^3 r\sqrt{(r \cos\theta - 3)^2 + (r \sin\theta)^2} \, dr \, d\theta \, dy \\
&= 96.
\end{align}

---

From the comments, $18\pi$ falls out as the solution if $x$ is not properly shifted over from the origin. Also, Wikipedia is a fairly good source for this material as well.

Comment: I don't understand why is it from 0 to $2\pi$. The cylinder is shifted (and tangent to the y-z plane) so It's not centred in the origin (if so, that would be from $0$ to $2\pi$). So with this thought, the angle should be from $0$ to $\pi$. Could you explain how do you set the angle range ?

Comment: We're essentially shifting the perspective of where the origin is in the $xz$ plane by saying $x = r \cos\theta - 3.$ The Cartesian limits on the integrals would properly be, with no shifts and in order from outside to inside, $y \in (-1,0)$, $x \in (-6,0)$, $z \in (-\sqrt{9 - (x + 3)^2},\sqrt{9 - (x + 3)^2}).$ So if we go to shifted polar coordinates $x = r \cos\theta - 3$ and $z = r \sin\theta,$ these limits on $x$ and $z$ are only achieved if $r \in (0, 3)$ and $\theta \in (0, 2\pi).$

Comment: ohh, Eureka! you made me understand! Now everything is at the right place. I know how to simplify the integral, without using the shifted polar coordinates It's much more simple. The Flux is also equal to $\int_{\pi/2}^{3/2\pi}\int_{0}^{-6cos(\theta)}\int_{-1}^{0}r^2dydrd\theta=96$!

Comment: That's it, you got it! Unless you mean 96 factorial - then we might have a little problem on our hands, ha. Anyways, glad I could help.